# What are the strange words on back of idol from India in Devanagari script?

Tags: language, art, history

[image]A close friend showed me photographs of the reverse side which has numerous words inscribed in Devanagari. I'm unable to decipher a single word. Some of the words are clear but contain archaic forms of the script, perhaps.
Please anyone able to say which language it is in will be an enormous help.